# Space between lines on receipt when printing orders

Tags: php, printing, character, letter

[image]When my restaurant orders are printed out, some of the lines isnt in order on the print and there are space between some of the lines. Can anyone help? When smaller variants are chosen they fit one seperat line on the paper fine, but when the word in the variant is longer it doesnt change line nicely between the words and createas a lot of space between them which createas a gap.
Thanks you :)

```
private function printHeder(){
    $this->printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printer->selectPrintMode(Printer::MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH);
    if(config('settings.hide_project_branding',true)){
        $this->printer->text("#".$this->order->id);
    }else{
        $this->printer->text(config('app.name')." #".$this->order->id);
    }
    $this->printer->selectPrintMode();
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
    $this->printer->text($this->order->restorant->name);
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printer->text($this->order->created_at->format(config('settings.datetime_display_format')));
    $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printLine();
}



private function printClient(){
    if($this->order->client){
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text(__("Customer").":");
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text($this->order->client->name);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text($this->order->client->phone);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
        $this->printer->feed();
    }else{
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text(__("Customer").":");
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text($this->order->getConfig('client_name',""));
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text($this->order->getConfig('client_phone',""));
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
        $this->printer->feed();
    }
    
}

private function printAddress(){
    if($this->order->address){
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text(__("Address").":");
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text($this->order->address?$this->order->address->address:"");
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
        $this->printer->feed();
    }

    if (!empty($this->order->whatsapp_address)){
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text(__("Address").":");
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text($this->order->whatsapp_address);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
        $this->printer->feed();
    }
   
    
}

private function printTable(){
    if($this->order->table){
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text(__("Area").": ".$this->order->table->restoarea->name);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text(__("Table").": ".$this->order->table->name);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
        $this->printer->feed();
    }
    
}

private function printPaymentStatus(){
    $this->printer->text(__("Payment method").": ".__(strtoupper($this->order->payment_method)));
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printer->selectPrintMode(Printer::MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH);
    $this->printer->text(__(ucfirst($this->order->payment_status)));
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printer->selectPrintMode();
}

private function printDeliveryOrDine(){
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printer->text(__("Delivery method").": ".$this->order->getExpeditionType());
    $this->printer->feed(2);
    if(strlen($this->order->time_formated)>2){
        $this->printer->selectPrintMode(Printer::MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH);
        $this->printer->text(__("Time slot"));
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->selectPrintMode();
        $this->printer->text($this->order->time_formated);
        $this->printer->feed();
    }
}


private function printItemsForKOT(){
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printLine();
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printer->setPrintLeftMargin(0);
    $this->printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
    $this->printer->selectPrintMode();
    $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
    $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify("    ".__('QTY'),__('Item'),60,40,32)));
    $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
    $this->printer->feed();
    foreach ($this->order->items as $key => $item) {
        $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify($item->pivot->qty, $item->name,76,24,32))."\n");

        if(strlen($item->pivot->variant_name)>3){
            $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify(__('Variant:'),$item->pivot->variant_name,30,70,32))."\n");
        }
    
        if(strlen($item->pivot->extras)>3){
            foreach (json_decode($item->pivot->extras) as $key => $extra) {
                $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify("",$extra,5,95,32))."\n");
            }
        }
    }
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printer->feed();
}

private function printItems(){
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printLine();
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printer->setPrintLeftMargin(0);
    $this->printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
    $this->printer->selectPrintMode();
    $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
    $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify("    ".__('Item'),__('Price')." (".config('settings.cashier_currency').")",60,40,32)));
    $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
    $this->printer->feed();
    foreach ($this->order->items as $key => $item) {
        $theItemPrice= ($item->pivot->variant_price?$item->pivot->variant_price:$item->price);
        $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify($item->pivot->qty." X ".$item->name,$item->pivot->qty*$theItemPrice,76,24,32))."\n");

        if(strlen($item->pivot->variant_name)>3){
            $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify(__('Variant:'),$item->pivot->variant_name,30,70,32))."\n");
        }
    
        if(strlen($item->pivot->extras)>3){
            foreach (json_decode($item->pivot->extras) as $key => $extra) {
                $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify("",$extra,5,95,32))."\n");
            }
        }
    
    }
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printer->text(__("Comment").": ".$this->order->comment."\n");
    $this->printer->feed();
}


private function printTotals(){
    $this->printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
    $this->printer->selectPrintMode();
    $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
    $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify(__('Subtotal'),config('settings.cashier_currency')." ".$this->order->order_price,60,40,32)));
    $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
    $this->printer->feed();
    $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
    $this->printer->feed();

    if($this->order->discount>0){
        $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify(__('Discount'),config('settings.cashier_currency')." ".$this->order->discount,60,40,32)));
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
        $this->printer->feed();
    }

    if($this->order->delivery_price>0){
        $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify(__('Delivery'),config('settings.cashier_currency')." ".$this->order->delivery_price,60,40,32)));
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
        $this->printer->feed();
    }
```

}

Comment: There are some points where you have `$this->printer->feed();` after `setEmphasis(false)`, which another `feed()` in front of that.  Do you need these extra `feed()` calls?

Comment: I don't think you'll get a useful answer to this question. We have no idea what your `printer` object actually does.

Comment: Sorry I have uploaded a photo - hope it helps:)